# Three different designs, Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I am creating a large site that is based on three different templates:

- First: Home Page - I know I can copy page.tpl.php and use
  page--front.tpl.php for this
- Second: All secondary pages will be
  based on this template design
- Third: All other pages will be based on
  this template design

Here are my questions:

- How do I create the other two?
- Assuming the process is the same I use for creating the front page would I simply call the second template page--second.tpl.php and the same process for the third?

If this is correct, how would I specify which template (second or third) to use when adding new pages?

If this isn't correct, could someone please assist with where I am wrong?

Thanks!

B

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done by creating different tpl.php files for each content type. You will need a separate content type for your home page, secondary pages, and all other pages. For example, for your secondary pages, you will need to make a new content type called "Secondary Page" with a machine name of secondary_page". Copy the page.tpl.php file and rename it to node--secondary_page.tpl.php (assuming you are on Drupal 7).

Flush your site cache (under the Performance menu), and all content you create with the "Secondary Page" content type will follow that new template file.